# Process execution and logging of output of subsubprocesses

Tags: visual-studio, scala, build-automation, processbuilder

We use jenkins for build automation of a Visual Studio 2008 C++ Project.
In essence it's a series of calls of:

```
devenv solution_name /build configuration_name [/Project project_name]
```

which works fine in general.

To run everything out of a dos box I wrote a scala wrapper, which does the same with ProcessBuilder. It works, but I have the problem, there is not output on the console.

My guess: devenv starts a bunch of processes to compile and linke the projects in parallel. My scala programm only outputs the stdout and stderr of the devenv process, which is none. All the other output of the subprocesses is shot into nirvana.

for the sake of completness the source snippet:

```
def buildProject(branch: String, mode: Mode) = {

  import scala.sys.process._

  val lb = new ListBuffer[String]()
  lb.append("devenv")
  lb.append(solution)
  lb.append(mode.cmd)
  lb.append(config.asString)
  if (!"".equals(project))
    lb.append(project)

  val printLogger = ProcessLogger(line => println(line), line => println(line))

  val errorLevel = Process(lb.toList, new File(branch, work.sv)) ! printLogger
  if (errorLevel != 0)
    throw new RuntimeException("Project build failed.")
}
```

The List used to start the process looks like:

```
List(devenv, Libraries/Libraries.sln, /rebuild, Release)
```

Is there a way to record/output the output of the subprocesses?

Comment: The answer in the linked question is part of my solution allready. It deals with capturing the output in general. In my specific case, I need to capture the output of the subprocess of the process I started and the output is allready captured.

Comment: What happens if you, on the console, dump the output of devenv into a file, e.g., devenv > output.txt. Is the output of the sub-processes also dumped to the file? In that case, it seems strange that the output is not caught by the ProcessLogger.

Comment: I redirected the stdout to a file and it worked as expected. Strange for sure...